# php form arrays and sqlite - updated

Tags: php, sqlite

I need some help I am trying to create a PHP form using sqlite3 database. I am looking up values from from an existing sqlite3 database in the "lookuptable" where the column "id = 340" and display those values as a dropdown selection. Then once the value is selected by the user  then the form is submitted by the user which updates the new value in the "roster" table with the values from the php form. I get it to display the names in the dropdown but when I click on the update button to submit the data it updates what the value is in the array.

How do I post "firstname" and "lastname" from the user to the roster table instead of of the number on the array table?

### PHP entry page Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<div class = "controlbox">
<body style="font-size:12;font-family:verdana">
<form action="post.php" method="post">
<p> 
<h1>  </h1>
<br>
<br>
Person : <select name="name">
<option>--Available Options--</option>
<?php
try
{
$db = new PDO("sqlite:DefaultLibrary.db");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
}
catch(Exception $e)
{   
echo $e->getMessage();
}

$stmt2 = $db->query ("SELECT * FROM lookuptable where ID = '340' ");
$rowarray = $stmt2->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$cntr = 0;

foreach($rowarray as $row)
{
 echo "<option value = $cntr >$row[FirstName] $row[LastName]</option>";
 $cntr++;
}
?>

</select><br>

<p>
<input type="submit" name="update" value="update">
</p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### PHP Code: Post.php

```
<?php

$name = sqlite_escape_string($_POST['name']);

try
{
 $db = new PDO("sqlite:DefaultLibrary.db");
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
}
catch(Exception $e)
{   
echo $e->getMessage();
}

if (!empty($person)) {
try
{   
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE roster SET rotationplace = :name WHERE ID = '340'");
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

    echo "submitted successfully";


    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you try to make your question more evident?

Comment: `table1` and `table2` are appalling names for database tables. And `slot1` isn't great either (unless this is referring to a slot machine...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
echo "<option value = $INSERT_NAME_HERE_NOT_COUNTER >$row[FirstName] $row[LastName]</option>";
```

Comment: echo "<option name = $name >$row[FirstName] $row[LastName]</option>";

Everything else is the right syntax